# Get all cell contents throughout file into a single cell

Tags: excel, csv, formatting, excel-2010, string-formatting

I have a CSV file will about 80 rows. Only the first column has data (email address)

I want to get all the email addresses, into a single cell, seperated by a comma.
For example:

`1 Bob@microsoft.com
    2 Mary@microsoft.com
    3 Rob@microsoft.com`

So it looks like this instead:

`1 Bob@micrsoft.com, Mary@microsoft.com, Rob@microsoft.com
    2
    3`

Can you please advise? I'm using excel 2010.
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  If you search this site you will find multiple solutions.

Comment: I found similar questions for the reverse. Couldn't find one with this issue.

Comment: Try a different search term